# Fetching user connections to pages using RestFB not returning values

Tags: facebook, grails, restfb

I'm using grails with RestFB to write a facebook canvas/page application. After obtaining a valid access token using the oauth login process, I try to fetch the user connection to pages in order to present options to the user. I use the following code:

```
List getPages() {
   FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(this.accessToken)
   List pages = []
   Connection<Page> connection = client.fetchConnection("/me/accounts", Page.class)

   pages.addAll(connection.data)

   while(connection.hasNext()) {
       connection = client.fetchConnectionPage(connection.nextPageUrl, Page.class)
       pages.addAll(connection.data)
   }

   return pages
}
```

This call sometimes works and returns the users pages. However, sometimes the connection object returns an empty data list. If I try the same access token using the Graph API Explorer, the list of pages is always returning.

Can someone try to help me figure out why the list is empty sometimes if I use restfb but is never empty if I use the Graph API explorer?

Answer (score -2):

```
List <Page> getPages() {
   FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(acces_token);

   Connection<Page> connection = client.fetchConnection("/me/accounts", Page.class);

   return connection.getData();
}


//call getPage()

List <Page> pages = getPages();
for(Page p:pages){
    System.out.println(p.getname());
}
```

try this code.

Comment: This answer completely neglects to take paging into account.

Comment: Doesn't work.... Page list is empty